# ERC20 tokens program

Tags: solidity, erc-20

i am new ro ERC20. Please tell me how to code this

create a smart contract with the following requirements:

1. Create an ERC20 contract for Token A and Token B.
2. Then write a smart contract. with the below functionality
3. User should be able to deposit the tokenA to the smart contract and get tokenB in a proportion of 100:1 by minting
4. User should be able to withdraw tokenA from the smart contract and burn the tokenB in proportion of 100:1

---

I am able to transfer 100TokenA and withdraw the same but unable yo perform returning 1TokenB after depositing 100TokenA similarly unable to burn 1TokenB after withdrawal of 100TokenA

Comment: For 1. just use OpenZeppelin, 2 isn't a real requirement. 3 & 4 are the real requirements. What did you try?

Comment: I am able to transfer 100TokenA and withdraw the same but unable yo perform returning 1TokenB after depositing 100TokenA similarly unable to burn 1TokenB after withdrawal of 100TokenA

Comment: Show the code used, so we can suggest a fix.